# Downloaded Xcode 5.0.2, crashes whenever I try and open a .xib file

Tags: ios, xcode

Whenever I try and edit/open a .xib file my xcode crashes, I have no idea what the issue is, I've tried reinstalling xcode,reinstalling my OS, and disabling auto layout in the .xib file using view source

Comment: Is there any reason you are using such an old version of Xcode?

Comment: y r u not using latest XCode ?

Comment: In which Version of Xcode u created the Xibies ?

Comment: the lowest you can use is Xcode 5.1 for using Auto Layout

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 5 is obsolete. Download Xcode 6.4 and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Very often XIB gets corrupted when u open your project in different Xcode versions,Xcode asks you whether you want to update these interface file ,and once u do it ,it gets corrupted sometime.   Are you sure that your XIB file is not corrupted ? in that case u won't be able to open from any xcode version

To know that XIB is corrupted or not , just open it in textedit,you can see some garbage characters,unclosed XML tags if that file is corrupted.